# Highcharts: Disconnect line when there's no data for position

Tags: highcharts

in my project I'm using highcharts/stockcharts. See my JS-fiddle example for a simple graph with X-axis 1 to 10, but no data for "position 9". I want no line to be drawn between 8 and 10, since there is no data for 9.

I've been playing with the `connectNulls` option, but that only works when providing `null` as value for position 9. Since Highcharts figures out the intervals by itself I hoped it would recognise on its own that there's no data for that position. Is there any way to make Highcharts not draw a line between 8 and 10 without specifying `null` for position 9?

Thanks in advance for your replies.

http://jsfiddle.net/bnqhuqt3/

Comment: Without adding the null value, not that I am aware of. A null value is the method for breaking the line, along with connectNulls: false. You'll have to process your data to determine where null values are needed.

Comment: Hi, as jlbriggs mentioned, if you want to break your line you need to use data with null values. If you don't want to add this value manually, you can make custom function that will add it for you. I have made an example how it can work:http://jsfiddle.net/bnqhuqt3/3/

Answer (score 0):

You can not cut a line in a serie. You need to define a new `data` for **series**

```
   series: [{
      data: [
        [1, 98.87],
        [2, 98.45],
        [3, 98.52],
        [4, 99.34],
        [5, 98.56],
        [6, 98.61],
        [7, 98.12],
        [8, 98.03],
      ]
    }, {
      data: [
        [10, 0],
        [11, 150]
      ]
    }]
```

[Fiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/bnqhuqt3/1/)